# Dumping blob rows to files from MySQL

Tags: mysql, flat-file

I have a table with a few thousand rows in it that has a few integer columns and a blob column. I want to dump each row out as its own file with the blob being the content and the integers being used to form the file name. This is a one time op so quick and dirty is OK. One constraint is that I have almost no tools installed in this enviornment so that will be part of the dev cost no matter what I use.

---

*Edit:* I ended up using C# from another box. It only took downloading [a single assembly](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.1.html) and about the same amount of code as given in the answers below.

Comment: What kind of environment is that, especially the OS/distribution?

Comment: I have WinXP and Linux via SSH avalable

Answer (score 2):

Something quick in PHP:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("mysqlserver.example.com", "username", "password");
mysql_select_db("dbname");
$sql = "SELECT `blob_column`, `id` FROM `mytable`";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    file_put_contents("file" + $row["id"] + ".dat", $row["blob_column"]);
}
mysql_close($connection);
```

You could probably do something simular with whatever method you have to access MySQL, but AFAIK, there's no way to do it with pure SQL.

Comment: nice and simple +1, how hard is it to install PHP and set up MySQL support for it?

Comment: @BCS: Most servers (especially UNIX) ones come with PHP already installed.  If you have SSH/telnet access, you can type php -v at the command prompt to find out if it's available.  PHP should have been compiled with MySQL support as well.  If you don't have it though, you can install a package like Apache Friends XAMPP, but that may be too bloated for your usage (it comes with Apache, MySQL, PHPMyAdmin, and a ton of other stuff too).

Comment: Oh, and one more thing, you'll need to connect to your DB as well, I'm going to add that code in here too.

Comment: "-bash: php: command not found" I own the box and haven't installed much that I haven't needed already

Answer (score 1):

In Common Lisp, using CLSQL, something like the following should work (untested, don't have MySQL installed at the moment):

```
(require 'clsql)
(require 'clsql-mysql)

(clsql:connect (host db user password port) :database-type :mysql)

(clsql:do-query ((col1 col2 blob) "select col1,col2,blob from blobtable")
  (with-open-file (outfile (format nil "~a-~a" col1 col2)
                           :direction :output
                           :element-type 'byte)
    (write-sequence blob outfile)))
```

You would have to fill in host, db etc. (port is optional), and adjust the query, of course.