# I want to export mysql blobs into files in a directory, is there a better way other than select into dumpfile?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, blob

I have a table in mysql that contains attachments as blobs. Its approximately 13GB.
I would like to export them to files in a directory so that users can access them via directory path instead of from the database.

I did a small research and got a few suggestions, but the process seems to take far too much time than I would expect. Below is a sample procedure that would loop the table and export all blobs and named using column filename.

```
begin
declare this_id VARCHAR(255);
declare cur1 cursor for select DISTINCT(filename) from fileattachment where filename is not null;
open cur1;
  read_loop: loop
    fetch cur1 into this_id;
    set @query = concat('select attachment from fileattachment where filename is not null and filename="', 
        this_id, '" into DUMPFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/', this_id,'"');
    prepare write_file from @query;
    execute write_file;
  end loop;
close cur1;
end
```

I have approximately 30,000 rows of around 300Kb each. This procedure takes around 1min to export a single file and hangs on the 5th file.

I tried running a single query to see if it makes any difference but I noted that my memory fills up to 13GB before this query executes. I'm imagining it is loading the entire database to memory even if I'm exporting one file

```
select attachment from fileattachment where filename is not null and filename='kiki.jpg' 
 into DUMPFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/kiki.jpg';
```

I'm I missing something that can optimize this, or is there a better/different way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out that the real issue was that doing it within MySQL which ends up with *read/write locks*. The trick is to do a separately script, so I modified some php code([from MiffTheFox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051398/dumping-blob-rows-to-files-from-mysql)) utilizing *file_put_contents* to save to file. Also you may have to temporarily increase mysql *query_cache_size*, and if you are doing it from a separate machine *packet size*.

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "****", "****");
mysql_select_db("myHugedatabase");
$sql = "select attachment,filename from fileattachment where filename is not null";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if(!$result){
trigger_error("dbget: ".mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
    return false;
}

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '$row["filename"]';
    file_put_contents($row["filename"], $row["attachment"]);
}
mysql_close($connection);
?>
```